# Blender Crashes when Baking High Resolution Textures "Circular Dependency" error

Tags: texturing, texture-baking, baking, photogrammetry

I have a high poly (1,3 Mio faces) photo scanned mesh with 17 generated 8k textures (totalling 500 MB)

All the texture are looking something like this one here:
[image: generated texture example]
[image: 17 materials]

My goal is to bake those 17 diffuse maps into one single 8k texture. But when I hit "Bake" I first get some errors, which look like this:

```
Circular Dependency for image "texture_xy" from object "xyz"
```

and then Blender crashes.

[image: errors while baking]

First of all I want to know why those errors occur. But I am also concerned, that Blender doesn't crash because of the errors, but rather because those textures are just to massive in size.

Any suggestions on techniques I can use to bring those 17 textures into 1 single texture?
Would it help to decrease the polygon count of the mesh?

Comment: I'm sadly not very proficient with baking yet, but found this under "Circular dependency", maybe it could help shine some light on your problem: [cycles bake script error: “Circular dependency ..”](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44525/cycles-bake-script-error-circular-dependency)

Comment: Yeah, I'll check it out, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was just that I did not have sufficient memory. So I had to downscale the high resolution textures to make it work